# How can I vectorize longest common substring across data.table columns in R

Tags: r, string, data.table, substring, lcs

**How can I create a function that will allow me to EITHER quickly calculate the # of characters in the longest common substring OR return the longest common substring between TWO OR MORE COLUMNS in a large data.table in R?**

I modified this question's answer: [Find length of overlap in strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48701107/find-length-of-overlap-in-strings) but have 1.) issues applying across vector as this fails with blanks and other string features when applied to create a new column of results using sapply, 2.) issues applying across more than 2 columns, and 3.) the given answers do not include spaces in potential matches, and I'd like to. The function also is slow, and I'd like to apply across big data.

**Create Sample Data:**

```
sampdata <- data.frame(
  str1=c("Doug Olivas", "GRANT MANAGEMENT LLC", "LUNA VAN DERESH", "wendy t marzardo", "AMIN NYGUEN COMPANY LLC", "GERARDO CONTRARAS", "miguel martinez","albert marks porter"),
  str2=c("doug olivas", "miguel grant", "LUNA VAN DERESH MANAGEMENT LLC", "marzardo", "amin nyguen llc", "gerardo contraras", "miggy martinez","albert"),
  str3=c("Martin Olivas", "GRANT PROPERTIES", "luna company", "wendy marzardo", "the company of amin nyguen llc", "gerardo c", "miguel t martinez","")
  )
```

**MADE UP FUNCTION "lcsfoo" DESIRED FUNCTIONALITY 1:**

```
#option type="nchar" to return number of characters INCLUDING SPACES, IGNORING CASE in max common substring
sampdata$desired_LCSnchar <- lcsfoo(sampdata$str1,sampdata$str2,sampdata$str3,type="nchar")

#option type="str" to return the string INCLUDING SPACES, IGNORING CASE of the longest common substring between the columns
sampdata$desired_LCSstr <- lcsfoo(sampdata$str1,sampdata$str2,sampdata$str3,type="str")
```

#DESIRED RESULTS 1: The above would return the following for the sample data

```
sampdata$desired_LCSnchar <- c(7,5,5,8,12,9,9,0)
sampdata$desired_LCSstr<- c(" olivas","grant","luna ","marzardo","amin nyguen ","gerardo c"," martinez","")
```

****IDEALLY lcsfoo would also take variable numbers of column inputs (i.e 2 columns here instead of the 3 above):**

```
sampdata$str1str2_LCSnchar <- lcsfoo(sampdata$str1,sampdata$str2,type="nchar")
sampdata$str1str2_LCSstr <- lcsfoo(sampdata$str1,sampdata$str2,type="str")
```

#DESIRED RESULTS 2: The above would return the following for the sample data

```
sampdata$str1str2_LCSstr<- c("doug olivas","grant","luna van deresh","marzardo","amin nyguen ","gerardo contraras"," martinez","albert")
sampdata$str1str2_LCSnchar <- c(11,5,15,8,12,17,9,6)
```

I'd also need the function to work across BIG DATA:

```
library(data.table)
###Create sample big data from previous sampledata and apply on huge DT
samplist <- lapply(c(1:1000),FUN=function(x){sampdata})
bigsampdata <- rbindlist(samplist)

DESIRED FUNCTION APPLIED ON BIG DATA: 
bigsampdata$desired_LCSnchar <- lcsfoo(bigsampdata$str1,bigsampdata$str2,bigsampdata$str3,type="nchar")
bigsampdata$desired_LCSstr <- lcsfoo(bigsampdata$str1,bigsampdata$str2,bigsampdata$str3,type="str")
```

Comment: Unclear what you are asking, where is the definition of `lcsfoo()`?

Comment: A made up non-working function as an example