# How can I determine the longest common substring in two columns of a LARGE data.table in R

Tags: r, string, data.table, substring, lcs

I modified this question's answer: [Find length of overlap in strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48701107/find-length-of-overlap-in-strings) but have issues applying to big data as the iteration is slow.

**How can I improve the function below which finds the longest common overlap between two strings anywhere in the two strings (disregarding case)?**

*Slow function that works, but I'd like to replace with a better one:*

```
strlcs <- function(str1, str2,type="lcs") {
  
  
  if(nchar(str1) < nchar(str2)) {
    x <- str2
    str2 <- str1
    str1 <- x
  }
  
  x <- strsplit(str2, "")[[1L]]
  n <- length(x)
  s <- sequence(seq_len(n))
  s <- split(s, cumsum(s == 1L))
  s <- rep(list(s), n)
  
  for(i in seq_along(s)) {
    s[[i]] <- lapply(s[[i]], function(x) {
      x <- x + (i-1L)
      x[x <= n]
    })
    s[[i]] <- unique(s[[i]])
  }
  
  s <- unlist(s, recursive = FALSE)
  s <- unique(s[order(-lengths(s))])
  
  i <- 1L
  len_s <- length(s)
  while(i < len_s) {
    lcs <- paste(x[s[[i]]], collapse = "")
    check <- grepl(lcs, str1, fixed = TRUE)
    if(check) {
      if(type=="nchar"){
        return(nchar(lcs))
      }else{
        return(lcs)
      }
      break
    } else {
      i <- i + 1L 
    }
  }
}
```

*Sample data:*

```
library(data.table)
sampdata <- data.frame(
  str1=c("Doug Olivas", "GRANT MANAGEMENT LLC", "LUNA VAN DERESH", "wendy t marzardo", "AMIN NYGUEN COMPANY LLC", "GERARDO CONTRARAS", "miguel martinez","albert marks porter"),
  str2=c("doug olivas", "miguel grant", "LUNA VAN DERESH MANAGEMENT LLC", "marzardo", "amin nyguen llc", "gerardo contraras", "miggy martinez","albert"),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

###Create sample big data from previous sampledata and apply on huge DT
samplist <- lapply(c(1:10000),FUN=function(x){sampdata})
bigsampdata <- rbindlist(samplist)
```

**The above function is NOT optimized for big data.**

How do I make the following happen in less than the currently brutal 20+ seconds?

```
DESIRED FUNCTION APPLIED ON BIG DATA: 
system.time(bigsampdata$desired_LCSnchar <- sapply(c(1:nrow(bigsampdata)),FUN=function(x){strlcs(tolower(bigsampdata$str1[x]),tolower(bigsampdata$str2[x]),type="lcs")}))
   user  system elapsed 
 24.290   0.008  24.313
```

Comment: In words, what does `strlcs()` do?

Comment: See edit to the top

Comment: What would the longest substring here: `"doug olivas", "doug olds"` should be `doug ol` or would `doug` be enough?

Answer (score 2):

I have found a faster solution using the `LCS` function in the `qualV` package:

```r
library(data.table)
library(qualV)

strlcs_op <- function(str1, str2) {
    v1 <- unlist(strsplit(str1, ""))
    v2 <- unlist(strsplit(str2, ""))
    
    return(paste(v1[LCS(v1, v2)$va], collapse = ""))
    
}

# same as yours but with data.table syntax
system.time(bigsampdata[, desired_LCSnchar := mapply(strlcs,
                                                     tolower(str1),
                                                     tolower(str2))])
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   41.64    0.04   42.20
# optimised function
system.time(bigsampdata[, desired_LCSnchar := mapply(strlcs_op,
                                                     tolower(str1),
                                                     tolower(str2))])
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    4.58    0.00    4.75
```

You can speed it up further by parallelising the `mapply` with `mcmapply`

Comment: I get a slightly different result for ```str1="GRANT MANAGEMENT LLC"``` and ```str2="miguel grant"```: the slow function returns ```"grant"``` but your function returns ```"mgent"```. Any idea why it would be right on the others but not on that example? I think it may be taking non continuous substrings too? I've had some weird issues like this when I tried ```LCS``` from ```qualV``` before

Comment: I believe `qualV` finds the longest common subsequence which is a slightly different problem to the longest common substring. Subsequences don't have to be contiguous which is why it matches `mgent`.

Comment: @NealBarsch @Paul you are both right the  `LCS` function takes the longest subsequence i.e. `str1 <- "axbc";str2 <- "abyc";strlcs_op(tolower(str1),tolower(str2));` I'll check if there is an easy way to reuse the source `lcs`  https://github.com/cran/qualV/blob/master/src/lcs.c

Answer (score 1):

I implemented Wikipedia's solution [pseudocode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem#Pseudocode) in `c++` using `Rcpp`.

```
library(Rcpp)


cppFunction('
String largeset_common_substring(String str1, String str2) 
{ 
    std::string S = str1;
    std::string T = str2;
    int r = S.length();
    int n = T.length();
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > L(r , std::vector<int>(n));
    int z = 0;
    std::string ret;

    for (int i = 0; i < r; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            if (S[i] == T[j])
            {
                if (i == 0 || j == 0)
                    L[i][j] = 1;
                else
                    L[i][j] = L[i - 1][j - 1] + 1;
 
                if (L[i][j] > z)
                {
                    z = L[i][j];
                    ret = S.substr(i - z + 1, z);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                L[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
} 
')
```

```
largeset_common_substring(tolower("GRANT MANAGEMENT LLC"), "miguel grant")
#> [1] "grant"
```

Here is the timing for your big dataset.

```
library(data.table)
sampdata <- data.frame(
  str1=c("Doug Olivas", "GRANT MANAGEMENT LLC", "LUNA VAN DERESH", "wendy t marzardo", "AMIN NYGUEN COMPANY LLC", "GERARDO CONTRARAS", "miguel martinez","albert marks porter"),
  str2=c("doug olivas", "miguel grant", "LUNA VAN DERESH MANAGEMENT LLC", "marzardo", "amin nyguen llc", "gerardo contraras", "miggy martinez","albert"),
  stringsAsFactors = F
)

###Create sample big data from previous sampledata and apply on huge DT
samplist <- lapply(c(1:10000),FUN=function(x){sampdata})
bigsampdata <- rbindlist(samplist)


system.time(
  bigsampdata[, desired_LCSnchar := purrr::map2_chr(
      tolower(bigsampdata$str1),
      tolower(bigsampdata$str2),
      largeset_common_substring
  )]
)
#> user  system elapsed 
#> 0.78    0.07    1.28
```

Comment: The function has the same issue `LCS` has `largeset_common_substring("axbc", "abyc")` is `abc`

Comment: I have check your function a bit further, and the issue I mention happens due to the `else if` clause. Erase that piece of the code and it will provide a satisfactory result (even if it is the leftmost one).

Comment: Thanks, @JonNagra. I misinterpreted the meaning of `∪` in the pseudocode to mean string concatenation. I've updated my answer.